# Запоминание введенного числа и использование

Tags: c#

Я сделал так: пишете число в textBox1, при нажатии на кнопки +,-,*,/ он обнуляет textBox1.
Что я хочу: написал число, нажал на одну из этих кнопок, чтобы он запомнил это число и обнулил, потом я ввожу следующее число и после при нажатии на = он выдал мне ответ, например, сумму того, запоминающего числа и нововведенного числа, т.е: ввел "3", нажал на "+" текстбокс обнулился, стал чистым, пом я ввожу "5" и при нажатии "=" он мне выдает их сумму, 8.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем собственно проблема? Заведите переменную или список для хранения чисел, ввели число, нажимаете соответствующий символ, который наверняка у вас определяется и обрабатывается, так вот в этом участке кода и сохраняйте до обнуления текстового поля число в предопределенную переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы только начали изучать языки программирования. Вам достаточно объявить 3 переменных (**FirstNumber**, **SecondNumber**, **Sign**) и при нажатии одного из мат. знаков, сохраняйте первое число в **FirstNumber**, знак - в **Sign**. После нажатия "Ок", сохраняйте второе число в **SecondNumber**. И потом, в зависимости от введённого знака (с помощью **switch-case**) разделите/прибавьте/перемножьте либо отнимите числа.

Для перевода числа в строку используйте

```
результат = int.Parse(/*какае-то строка*/);
```

Для перевода строки в число используйте

```
результат = /*число*/.ToString();
```